# Trying to create a simple socket using socket.io

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I am getting the error:

> Port error: Could not establish connection. Receiving end does not
>   exist.

but I can't figure out how to fix this, any help? Here's my code:

Server (app.js)

```
var app = require('express')(), 
    server = require('http').createServer(app), 
    io = require('socket.io').listen(server);

server.listen(8088);

//routing
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.sendfile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});

io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {

  socket.emit('news', { hello: 'world' });

  socket.on('set nickname', function (name) {
    socket.set('nickname', name, function () { socket.emit('ready'); });
  });

  socket.on('msg', function () {

    socket.get('nickname', function (err, name) {
      console.log('Chat message by ', name);
    });

  });

});
```

Client (index.html)

```
<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script>
  var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:8088');

  socket.on('news', function (data) {
    console.log(data);
  });

  socket.on('connect', function () {
    socket.emit('set nickname', prompt('What is your nickname?'));

    socket.on('ready', function () {
      console.log('Connected !');
      socket.emit('msg', prompt('What is your message?'));
    });

  });
</script>
```

**EDIT**

I removed `socket.connect()` from the client but still get the same error

Answer (score 1):

i have never used socket.connect() on the client side and i never saw that error, so i think that is where your error is comming from.

on the clientside

```
var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:8088')
```

should be the only thing you need to call to establish a connection, es ebohlman stated on the clientside there is no connect event, if you want to listen on that event u have to emit it yourself on the serverside.

```
io.sockets.on('connection',function(){
  socket.emit('connect',{...})
})
```

there is a simple example on the front page of http://socket.io/ which should get you started.

Comment: even without the socket.connect(); I get that error I guess I'm missing something else. The other thing is that it takes A LOT of time for me to get any message I think that's a known issue with socket.io

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, iosocket's `connect` event is something that gets fired on the server side when a client makes a connection, not something that gets fired on the client side when it makes a successful connection to the server. If I'm right, your client-side code should be responding to the "news" event (which it should see when the server acknowledges the connection) instead.

Answer (score 0):

Try port 3000 or 5000 instead of 8088

Answer (score 0):

His code looks fine.
On client side `socket.on("connect")` triggers when it is connected to the specified server.
It could be some port issue. Try different ports.
Here are some events on both client and server side
https://github.com/LearnBoost/socket.io/wiki/Exposed-events

Answer (score 0):

These kind of errors have nothing to do with your code, so you can ignore them. They don't interfere with your code. They originate from a browser extension, usually try'ng to connect to a local file. More posts can be found for that specific error. That's how I found out!